# Adobe Flash player Secuirty Pop-Up question

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash

I am building a Audio Recording tool using Flash and Wowza.

I dont want to start the recording until the use clicks the Allow Button is the Security Pop-up question represented here http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help05.html

In Audio I dont get this until I attach the stream to it. In Video can get thsi question when I attach the camera to Video.

I want to avoid making a connection until the user clicks Accept and this doesn't happen until I make the connection request in Audio.

I am able to display the http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help09.html pop-up using SecurityManager

Is there a way I can call the pop-up from my code. http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help05.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very last point in the last link you posted answers your question.

> **How can I display this question again?** 
>   You can't. Flash Player displays this
>   question automatically when necessary.

Sorry bout that!

Comment: YEah, I read that before. I thought I will confirm by posting at SO. Thanks!